# Is growth still possible for someone at age 15 if they're 5'9?

Tags: height

I'm 15 and 5'9, and half of my height is around my waist. I heard once that if half of your height is below the groin area, you're pretty much done growing. Is this true, or is it possible I still have a few more inches to grow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase body height?](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/how-to-increase-body-height)

Comment: Males and females stop growing at different ages, and for females it is strongly correlated to age of menarche.  No one here can answer specifically for your body.  But general principles can be discussed.

Comment: I think this question differs enough from the question you linked, but there ARE others that ask basically the same question. @user2791 please look at the links along the right side for similar questions.